# Challenging trigonometry review for a physic graduate

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, book-recommendation

Recently I graduated with a degree in physics but have always had a particularly hard time solving problems involving complex geometry and trig. I know the formula and how to solve for basic angles but a lot of the issues I have involve using the more geometric problem solving aspects in order to get to a point where I can find the angles involved. I also have a hard time picturing such systems in my head in order to think about how to go.

I have recently checked out Elementary and advanced trigonometry by Miller and Walsh, which did not seem to tackle the problems I am having with the subject, and Advanced Trigonometry by Durell and Robson which I did not like the writing style.

I was wondering if anyone has any recommended readings for someone in my position, particularly any focused the problem of finding angles, lengths, and other geometric aspects rather then focused on the mathematical theories.

Thank you

Comment: Possibly *Trigonometry* by Nobbs, or for a book with solutions, *Problems in Elementary Mathematics* by Lidsky. There's also *Problems in Plane Geometry* and *Problems in Solid Geometry* by Sharygin, both with solutions, but he doesn't clearly identify those problems that use trigonometry and those that don't. Nobbs' book is easier than the others, followed by Lidsky. Only a small part of Durell and Robson's book is actually about geometric uses of trigonometry, as it's mostly about trigonometric expressions and complex numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend *A Trigonometry Refresher* by A.A. Klaf, which is sold by Dover Books.  It's very simply written and understandable for those whose background isn't math.  (They have a section on slide rules that is dated unless you have a slide rule, but logarithms are still valid.)

Also, *Schaum's Outlines* has a book on trigonometry that is great for reference.

I have Durell and Robson's *Advanced Trigonometry*, which is more for those who are agile on theory but offers some pretty challenging exercises.  (I've been tempted to get the *Key* of their book, but it's in a college library in Toledo, OH.)  The writing style is not for everyone, and some of the chapters are somewhat intimidating.  Durell and Robson also have *Elementary Trigonometry,* but it's very rare book - and would probably be written in the same style.